# Why my helpers does not outputting nothing in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm new on rails and I have a book to study them. In one practice, I created a helper in my Application Helper, the test from RSpec work fine, until I have to print the result of my helper. No show any result and no error happens.

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def title(*parts)
        unless parts.empty?
            content_for :title do 
                (parts << "Ticketee").join(" - ")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% title(@project.name) %>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

and when I go to the show link I supposed to see "Random Project name - Ticketee", however only they show me "Ticketee".

Any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% title(@project.name) %>
```

Means don't show to the user

```
<%= title(@project.name) %>
```

Means show to the user - notice the equals.

Comment: OP sets the content with a `content_for` block. The helper function doesn't return the result directly.

Comment: do you have `yield :title` anywhere?

Comment: @HolgerJust How do I do that?